# How To Add A Column Conditionally When Importing Multiple csv

Tags: python, csv

Let's say I have multiple csv files:

`A010119.csv`,

`A010219.csv`,

`A010319.csv`,

...

`A013119.csv`.

When importing all these, I want to add a new column called 'date' that has a constant value. I want this constant value to be the date for each csv files where the dates are specified in the names of each csv file. For instance, "010119" from "A010119.csv", "010219" from "A010219.csv, and so on.

I know how to concat all these files, but just can't figure out how to add a column based on the file name. The below codes was used to concat:

```
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
all_files

li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

concated = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

To illustrate in detail, the first three files look like this:

```
age score
1   2
2   3
3   4
```

```
age score
2   3
3   4
4   5
```

```
age score
3   4
4   5
5   6
```

Desired result:

```
age score   date
1   2      010119
2   3      010119
3   4      010119
2   3      010219
3   4      010219
4   5      010219
3   4      010319
4   5      010319
5   6      010319
```

Comment: Just add the date column to each CSV before merging them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on what @AMC was suggesting:

```py
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    df['date'] = function_that_extracts_numeric_string_from_filename(filename)
    li.append(df)
```

I'll leave extracting that numeric substring up to you. If you can't work it out search on here it's a pretty common question.